# IllegalArgumentException : Executable name has embedded quote, split the arguments

Tags: java, exception, illegalargumentexception

I'm getting an error :

```
IllegalArgumentException : Executable name has embedded quote, 
split the arguments
```

While running the

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, envTokens, file1);
```

I'm using Windows7 and Java7 machine .

Same line of code is working fine for other environments .

Suggest me some way .

Comment: Show how your parameters `cmd`, `envTokens`, `file1` look like. Do they contain quotes?

Comment: my parameters doesn't contains quotes ... but they contains spaces between them and i have specified earlier that same line of code in working fine in other environments

Comment: you might be able to overcome this by protecting spaces inside by extra quotes or backslashes, but I think [this answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16890476/1734130) appears to address your issue, especially if you are running most recent JDK

Answer (score 15):

This happens because of a change in [Java 7 update 21](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u21-relnotes-1932873.html#jruntime)/[Java 6 update 45](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/6u45-relnotes-1932876.html).

The solution to your problem is to refactor your code to use [java.lang.ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead. For instance:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("command", "argument1", "argument2");
Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
env.put("var1", "value1");
Process p = pb.start();
```

Comment: can u suggest me some way to do it from Runtime.getRuntime().exec() only , if possible?

Comment: I guess splitting the cmd yourself and passing the array to exec (instead of the string with spaces) will still work.

Comment: i am getting the same error message with my source code in the blackberry compiler in eclipse. It says cant start compiler. then the message. What do i do? Where to look.?

Comment: Note that the same change was implemented in Java 6 update 45. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/6u45-relnotes-1932876.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your parameters in a String array:

```
    String a = quote(exeFullPath);        
    String b = paramB;
    String[] cmd = new String[]{a,b};
    Process myExec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, null, parentFolder);
```