# Java syntax escapting symbols?

Tags: java, syntax

I need to process a command in cmd and the command looks like this:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\HMA! Pro VPN\bin\HMA! Pro VPN.exe" -changeip
```

But I can't really add the `"`  because I will get errors..
Is there a way to do that? What i've tried causes errors:

```
cmd.exec(""c:/Program Files (x86)/HMA! Pro VPN/bin/HMA! Pro VPN.exe" -reconnect");
```

How can I escape that character so it works?

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Executable name has embedded quote, split the arguments
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.isQuoted(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.getExecutablePath(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at HMACommand.reconnect(HMACommand.java:15)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367322/what-are-all-the-escape-characters-in-java

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6

Answer (score 1):

You can escape characters using a backslash (`\`).

In your case the result will be this:

```
String test = "\"c:\\Program Files (x86)\\HMA! Pro VPN\\bin\\HMA! Pro VPN.exe\" -changeip";
```

You'll also have to escape the backslashes themselves.

Referring to your edit:

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890457/illegalargumentexception-executable-name-has-embedded-quote-split-the-argumen) explains why you get the error you're getting.

From [the cited source](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u21-relnotes-1932873.html#jruntime):

> On Windows platform, the decoding of command strings specified to `Runtime.exec(String)`, `Runtime.exec(String,String[])` and `Runtime.exec(String,String[],File)` methods, has been improved to follow the specification more closely. **This may cause problems for applications that are using one or more of these methods with commands that contain spaces in the program name**, or are invoking these methods with commands that are not quoted correctly.

Instead, use a `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: Read my edit please, I've got a few errors upon processing that command.

Comment: This is the answer I'd use. FYI you can also do "/c/Some directory/some stuff/" for cross platform support.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I see, but in the answer you sent me, I don't really understand why he created a map and then had the values "var1" and "Value1" if he already entered the command parameters inside ProcessBuilder?

Comment: @user3123545: I haven't got any experience with it myself, but as far as I can tell it is optional since this seems to indicate it automatically gets the values as defined in the `ProcessBuilder` constructor: `an environment, which is a system-dependent mapping from variables to values. The initial value is a copy of the environment of the current process (see System.getenv())`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) like so

```
String[] cmdLine =  {
        "c:/Program Files (x86)/HMA! Pro VPN/bin/HMA! Pro VPN.exe",
        "-changeip"
};
try {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmdLine);
    Process p = pb.start();
    p.waitFor();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```